# prepareForSegue não apresenta nenhuma ação no botão

Tags: objective-c

Sou relativamente novo nestas andanças da programação e deparei-me com uma questão que me ultrapassa completamente. Então eu tenho um menu com 6 UIButton definidos como IBOutlet no meu viewcontroller. Cada um desses UIButton chamam um html especifico alojado internamente no projecto Xcode. A questão é que ao usar a função prepareForSegue o xcode por e simplesmente ignora qualquer ação nos botões.

Esta é a minha função prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if (sender == self.Secretaria){
    uptPiso1WebViewController *vc = (uptPiso1WebViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Piso1/Secretaria/vtour/tour.html"]]];

} else if (sender == self.sala){
    uptPiso1WebViewController *vc = (uptPiso1WebViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Piso1/Sala105/vtour/tour.html"]]]; 
}
}
```

Mais uma vez relembro a minha inexperiência e peço desculpa se a minha pergunta possa estar demasiado vaga, mas o meu último recurso foi mesmo tentar encontrar uma solução aqui.

Cumprimentos

Comment: Você está usando storyboard? o botão está lá também?

Answer (score 1):

Criei um projeto para tentar simular o que ocorre com o seu, não tive os problemas que você encontrou, no entanto notei que quando você associa o valor para `vc.url`, imagino que essa propriedade seja uma `NSURL`, você cria corretamente uma NSURL a partir de uma String, mas ao invés de passar uma String, está passando um NSURLRequest com outra URL, isso causa um crash no app por `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Tente usar apenas:

`vc.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Piso1/Secretaria/vtour/tour.html"];`

E depois, na classe `uptPiso1WebViewController` chame o seguinte método na webview:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url];
[_webview loadRequest:request];
```

2 outros pontos para melhorar o código:

1. Não compare objetos com == como fez com os botões. Use `[sender isEqual:self.Secretaria]` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW61
2. Aprenda a usar http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Baixe o projeto: http://cl.ly/2I2E1B1e0Z33